# How to recognize an assembly "call" instruction within memory?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, disassembly, low-level

How is it possible to differentiate, in an process' executable memory, opcodes for the assembly "call" instruction (E8 [Address]) from other E8 bytes (e.g. one that is in the middle of another instruction)? (From a C language perspective, preferably)

Is it enough verifying if the four bytes just after the E8 byte refer to a valid address, and then verifying if that region (i.e. the start of the called function) starts with the bytes corresponding to the opcodes "push ebp" and "mov ebp,esp" (most functions use this prologue)? Or is there a better option, like checking every opcode from the entry point to the exit point?

By the way, I have little to no experience with this topic, so any information is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Proper interpretation starts from an address that is known to be the start of an instruction.

(This answer applies to processors with variable-length instructions, of course, such as Intel’s x86 architecture.)

When the processor is interpreting instructions, it always starts interpreting at a particular location because:

- it was the next location after the previously interpreted instruction,
- it was the target of a jump instruction (including returns from trap and other special instructions),
- it was the initial starting location when the processor is initialized, or
- it was the address in an interrupt table or other special data structure used in controlling the system.

All of these are locations that are known to be the starts of instructions because they were designed that way: We wrote software, and those locations are where we put instructions.

When interpreting an instruction, the processor follows rules about instruction encodings. It looks at the first byte, and the bits in that byte indicate whether the next few bytes are opcode, modifiers, or operands for the current instruction. Then it interprets the next bytes accordingly. So an E8<sub>16</sub> in the first byte of an instruction will be interpreted differently from an E8<sub>16</sub> byte elsewhere.

A disassembler starts where the user tells it to. Often, that is the address given by a label in the program (such as the name of a function) or other information such as the value of the current program counter or a return address found on the stack. These addresses are all the starts of instructions, so the disassembler interprets the bytes the same way the processor does.

Sometimes one might not have easy access to information about where instructions in a particular area start and might just tell the disassembler to start disassembling at an arbitrary address in the middle of a region. In this case, the first few disassembled instructions are likely to be wrong, since the disassembler is interpreting bytes starting at places that are not normally the starts of instructions. (A common example of this is that one is debugging and knows the current program counter, but wants to look backward at the most recent dozen or so instructions without starting from the beginning of the current routine. In this case, one might tell the disassembler to start disassembling 100 bytes back from the current program counter.) What frequently happens, though, is that, essentially by chance, one of the wrongly interpreted instructions happens to end in a spot where a proper instruction starts. Then the disassembler disassembles that instruction correctly, and it is synchronized with the proper instruction sequence, and the remaining disassembly proceeds correctly. As long as most instructions are short and the instructions lengths vary considerably, there is a high probability this occurs within a few instructions.

It is possible to play with instruction encodings and craft a sequence of bytes that represents two different instruction streams depending on where you start executing in it, so that the opcode bytes of one stream are modifier/operand bytes of the other and vice-versa. This is not done in normal programming but demonstrates that interpretation of bytes of instructions depends on the starting location.

Comment: Great answer. Here are a few more items for the list of where the processor gets the location of the first byte of an instruction: a) from the HOST RIP or GUEST RIP field of a VMCS; b) from the interrupt descriptor table; c) from the vector number in a SIPI.

Comment: @prl: Thanks, I added interrupt tables and “other”—no need to go into details to explain the general concept, I think.

Comment: Yes, I agree. And an exhaustive list would be difficult. I forgot the task structure, which your wording covers. :-)

Comment: @prl: I was going to say the [`syscall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) entry point, set with a `wrmsr` to `IA32_LSTAR`, or in user space a signal-handler.  I think the wording here covers it, and gets the message across clearly :)

Comment: The other special property that usually leads to decoding getting back in sync is that most bit-patterns code for short instructions or prefixes, especially the bit-patterns found inside other instructions as immediates or addressing-mode displacements.  e.g. zeros are common, and a ModR/M=0 codes for `al, [rax]` operands, with no displacement.  It might also be relevant that most long instructions have a `0F` escape byte, and a few other mandatory prefixes.  It's an interesting property of x86 machine code that might not be as robust if machine-code used Huffman coding or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes: If you think more information could be useful, feel free to add it. You could insert a section title with an <h1> tag before the current answer, then add another section after it discuss the 0F bytes and such. Or add a supplementary answer.

Comment: I just miss in this answer, that to truly precisely find *all* possible `call` opcodes, the problem is equal to "halting problem" (because if the code does obfuscate dynamically, then you need to run through it completely to be sure you have seen all configurations of opcodes, and to be sure you have ran "through it" = halting problem). I.e. the mathematically precise answer to the original question is "it's impossible", which was actually in the very first comment under Q.

Comment: @DaviFN BTW, this is usually a sign of "XY Problem" situation, i.e. you are probably trying to resolve some issue by not very sound approach. For example many similar issues boil down to the original case being people who want to amend/instrument some code, but don't have original source available, which they are trying to fix on the wrong side of issue (instead of throwing out the SW without sources, which is useless in long term, they try to create some hacks to work around with the current binary, and if they succeed partially, they just prolong the bad situation and make it more fragile).

Answer (score 2):

Disassembly for a variable length instruction set like x86, and a number of others, you have to start from known to be good entry points and disassemble in execution order, not necessarily linearly.

There is no guarantee that that will work as it is generally trivial to trip up a disassembler and cause it to fail.

A simple example, there are many ways to do this.

```
set flag
blah
blah
jump if flag to hello
put the first opcode byte but not the rest of the instruction here as data
hello:
real stuff here
```

I tend to keep track of the location of the first byte of every instruction and then which bytes are additional to an instruction, so that for every instruction when following a path or branch can be checked to see first if I have already hit that path, and second if a first byte is landing on top of a non-first byte.  This can be perfectly valid hand crafted code to trip up an assembler, or it could be some other reason you got tripped up elsewhere.

Compilers unless designed to or told to tend to not make code that has disassembly problems (in execution order not linearly).  But if you go back and say disassembly the classic video game roms, you may find these kinds of disassembly issues and then have to do more work, mostly code analysis, to determine which if either execution path was correct.

Fixed length instruction sets, that have a known alignment, you can disassemble linearly from just about anywhere, you have to tolerate unknown instructions as when you hit the data portions you will see a lot of that, but you can take the shortcut of not dealing with execution order.